# Can't add repository due to 'missing' fingerprint

Tags: apt, repository, php, nginx

I am trying to install nginx with php but when I am following a guide, like this one: http://www.justincarmony.com/blog/2011/10/24/setting-up-nginx-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-10-04/ I am always told to add that repository (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brianmercer/php) but I  can't.

I'll just get "Error: can't find signing_key_fingerprint at https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~nginx/+archive/php5" and when I go to that website I find that there is a fingerprint specified but still I get that error message. Is there anyway to specify it myself?

And for the last thing, how I can fix this so I can continue my installation towards a working nginx enviroment with php.

Thanks for your advice and better wisdom.

Comment: I am running ubuntu 10.04 LTS server version btw.

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8D0DC64F
$ sudo apt-get update
```

This solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and am not even sure you can fix it.

In the mean time, you can add this repo `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brianmercer/php5` as per this tutorial : http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/installing-nginx-php-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/